# Calling a function with arguments in lists

Tags: clojure

i have a function that takes 3 arguments

```
(defn times-changed-answer [rid qid csv-file] ...some code)
```

that counts for a user with (record-id) rid how many times he changed his answer with (question-code) qid. The data is in csv-file.

It works and i have tested it for multiple users.
Now i want to call this function for all users and for all questions.
I have a list of rids and a list of qids.

```
(def rid-list '(1 2 4 5 10)
(def qid-list '(166 167 168 169 180 141)
```

How could i call this function on all users for all questions?
The lists are of different length and the third argument (the file) is always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `for` list comprehension - it depends on what result you expect
here; here e.g.  `[rid qid result]` is returned for all of them:

```clj
(for [rid rid-list
      qid qid-list]
  [rid qid (times-changed-answer rid quid csv-file)])
```

If you want to have this in a map, you could e.g. `reduce` over that.

Comment: @MarcoGrassi, if this solves your question, please accept the answer.